# What are the relations between these two minimizations

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, convex-optimization

What are the relations between the minimization problems $\arg\min_{\mathbf{y}=A\mathbf{x}}\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert _{2}$
and $\arg\min_{\mathbf{x}}\left\Vert A\mathbf{x-y}\right\Vert _{2}$
?

Comment: Thanks a lot for any helpful answers!

Comment: Are you presuming $y \in {\cal R}(A)$?

Comment: Can you explain why you believe there is a relation?

Comment: copper.hat, let us assume $y$ is in the range.

Answer (score 2):

Great question! I wouldn't say there is no relation. Those are two quite closely related problems. The problem
$$
\min_x \|Ax - y\|
$$
is called the linear least-squares problem. Typically, $A$ will have more rows than columns---the problem is then called *overdetermined*. This problem corresponds to linear regression where you take more measurements than you have unknowns in your linear model. Most of the time, it doesn't make sense for $A$ to have more columns than rows, because then $A$ will have a nullspace and if $y$ lies in the range of $A$, there will be infinitely many solutions, all with objective value zero. It does happen though and is mostly interesting when $y$ is not in the range of $A$.

You can square the norm in the objective without changing the solutions. The optimality conditions of the problem can be written as the *normal equations*
$$
A^T A x = A^T b
$$
or as the *augmented system*
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 I & A \\
 A^T & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 r \\ x
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 y \\ 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $r := y - Ax$ is the least-squares residual.

When $A$ has more columns than rows however, the interesting problem is the second one: find the $x$ with least norm that lies on the subspace $Ax=y$
$$
\min_x \|x\| \quad \text{subject to} \ Ax=y.
$$
Here, you must assume that $y$ is in the range of $A$ or this problem has no solution. Now the optimality conditions of the minimum norm problem are
$$
 x - A^T z = 0, \quad Ax=y,
$$
where $z$ are Lagrange multipliers. They can be rewritten $A A^T z = y$ or
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 I & A^T \\
 A & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x \\ -z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\ y
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and they are quite similar to those of the least-squares problem.

Evidently, when $A$ is square and $y$ is in the range of $A$, they are the same problem $Ax=y$.

The real connection occurs when the problem is *regularized*, which you do when $A$ is rank deficient or ill conditioned. The regularized linear least-squares problem is
$$
\min_x \|Ax-y\|^2 + \delta^2 \|x\|^2,
$$
and the regularized least-norm problem is
$$
\min_{x,r} \|x\|^2 + \delta^2 \|r\|^2 \quad \text{subject to} \ Ax + \delta^2 r = y.
$$
Now what's interesting is that those two problems are perfectly equivalent: they are the same problem. You can verify that by checking that they have the same optimality conditions. They correspond to the initial problems where you performed the substitutions
$$
A \leftarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
A \\ \delta I
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
y \leftarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
y \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So those problems are quite tightly connected.

Answer (score 1):

No relation, unless $y=Ax$ has a unique solution.

If $y=Ax$ is not solvable, $\arg\min_{\mathbf{y}=A\mathbf{x}}\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert _{2}$ does not exist, but $\arg\min_{\mathbf{x}}\left\Vert A\mathbf{x-y}\right\Vert _{2}$ always exists.

If $y=Ax$ has infinitely many solutions, $x_0=\arg\min_{\mathbf{y}=A\mathbf{x}}\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert _{2}$ is unique, but $\arg\min_{\mathbf{x}}\left\Vert A\mathbf{x-y}\right\Vert _{2}$ has infinitely many choices. In this case, $x_0$ is among these choices and it is *the* choice with the shortest length.

If $y=Ax$ has a unique solution $x_0$, we have $\arg\min_{\mathbf{y}=A\mathbf{x}}\left\Vert \mathbf{x}\right\Vert _{2}=\arg\min_{\mathbf{x}}\left\Vert A\mathbf{x-y}\right\Vert _{2}=x_0$.